# Given that AB=AC and BY=CZ, prove that PY=PZ.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In this image

[image: Triangle]

$P$ is the point where $\overline{BY}$ and $\overline{CZ}$ cross.
$\Delta ABC$ is isosceles, and proving that $\Delta BPC$ is isosceles will be enough to show that $\overline{PY}=\overline{PZ}$, but I cannot determine a way to show that $\Delta BPC$ is isosceles.

Comment: information is not sufficient. is $BY$ is perpendicular to $AC$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. If it's not then could it be proven that PY is not necessarily equal to PZ? I'm confident that PY=PZ, but cannot prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general.

There can be two points $Y_1,Y_2$ on the side $AC$ such that $BY_1=BY_2$ where $Y_1$ is nearer to $A$.

On the other hand, there can be two points $Z_1,Z_2$ on the side $AB$ such that $CZ_1=CZ_2$ where $Z_1$ is nearer to $A$.

Now choose $Y_1,Z_2$. We can have $BY_1=CZ_2$, but $PY_1=PZ_2$ does not always hold.

Comment: Yes, I encountered this while trying. thank you. My daily vote limit reached, so I cannot upvote this, sorry.

Comment: Is there a way to formally prove this?

Comment: @JustinD: It is sufficient to show one counterexample to disprove the statement. You can take an equilateral triangle $ABC$ to make things easier.

Comment: @mathlove I'm not seeing how an equilateral triangle makes it easier. I can't come up with a counter example.

Comment: @JustinD: For example, let $A(1,\sqrt 3),B(0,0),C(2,0)$ and find $Y_1,Z_2$ such that $BY_1=BY_2=CZ_1=CZ_2=1.8$. Then, find $P$ and show that $PY_1\not=PZ_2$.